# C# FindIndex with parameters

Tags: c#, list, find, exists

I'm currently patching my game that i recently released.

I have a list of a class, which is called AppliedEffects. The list made from that class is named appliedEffects.
I want to access this list and find a specific value in an index, and then make a bool true or false depending of if that value exists in the list. It is for a powerup system, where the list is all the powerups currently active. The code for shooting bullets for instance, will then search if there is an item in the list with the ID of 1, because that is the ID of having the double bullets powerup.

I have come this far, and only have a small problem:

```
int ndx = PlayerStatus.appliedEffects.FindIndex(PlayerStatus.FindAE(XX,1);
```

where XX is, I don't know what to put. I edited this:

```
int ndx = Books.FindIndex(FindComputer);
private static bool FindComputer(Book bk)
{
    if (bk.Genre == "Computer")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Because in the code example, I could not send in which parameter I wanted to search for. The edited code looks like this:

```
public static bool FindAE(AppliedEffects ae, int id)
{
    if (ae.id == id)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I create an int, that will get the index of the list where the item with the value of ID 1 exists, then if that value is 1, because the ID is 1, it will set a bool to true, and false if not.
I wanted to send in a parameter for the ID, which the example does not, so that I can reuse the function for other ID checks. But then when I enter the parameter, I don't know what to put as appliedEffect (that's why I put XX).

I have also tried this:

```
if (PlayerStatus.appliedEffects.Exists(x => x.id == 1))
{
     PlayerStatus.doubleBullets = true;
}
```

which did not work, no clue why. I don't fully understand the concepts of the .Exists and .FindIndex, so maybe that's why I don't know how to use it. 
Basically I just want to be able to check if there is an item with a specific ID in the list, so that the game will know that I have the specific powerup and can set a bool to true and then false.
Note: ID is not index, ID is an int in my AppliedEffects class that knows which powerup it is.
I'm a little tired so if there's any thoughts/concerns, please write in the thread, I'll subscribe to the thread.

Comment: As an aside, any time you've got `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` you can replace it all with `return condition;`. So your `FindAE` method body can just be `return ae.id == id;` for example.

Comment: Opening with a link to your "product" just makes this whole thing seem like promo spam. Do we really need to know about your game to answer your problem? Maybe you should just remove it

Comment: @musefan Promo spam? I'm so happy over this game, I won awards for this and spent countless and again countless of nights with no sleep for it, why is there a problem for you that I want to share my game with the people that has helped me with it? This got me into my dream school. Why is there a problem for you that I tell some background about my issue?
I'm just being nice.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, that helped. Nice thing to know.

Comment: @FindusNeuman: Because you are promoting your product, which is not welcome on Stack Overflow. If your game is so successful then you shouldn't need to promote it, we will find it by ourselves if we care enough

Comment: @musefan It's not the purpose to promote it, as I said. The purpose is that it could be interesting with some background information. It feels extremely robotic to not accept people talking about what they are developing when they ask for help.

Comment: @FindusNeuman: If it concerns you so, then you could raise the question (about if it is ok to post a link to your game) on [meta.se] and see what the rest of the community thinks. You would likely get some interesting debate there regarding why you should or shouldn't include it. Best for us to not continue discussing it on here anyway

Comment: @musefan It does concern me so, because I only linked my game, which made you call it "promo spam". It's quite a big difference for a game to be successful and a game recieving great critique from senior game developers. That's very rude.
And for the record, that argument does not work; you will not find it if you care. Indie developers on Android are barely represented in sales, and my game is free. AAA-games are the only ones seen, due to their marketing power.

Comment: @FindusNeuman: Right, I think you obviously don't understand what "promo spam" means. It means you are promoting your product for personal gain. There is no need to include the link in the question, it does not support your issue and it adds no value. It is only useful in promoting your product, which is not what SO is about. If you want to go show people your game and have a discussion about it then go find a forum somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `FindIndex` will return `-1` if the requested element is not found.  Therefore, you would have to do something like so:

```
if(PlayerStatus.appliedEffects.FindIndex(ae => PlayerStatus.FindAE(ae, 1)) != -1)
{
    PlayerStatus.doubleBullets = true;
}
```

It would probably make more sense in your situation to use `Exists`, like you noted.  Try this:

```
if(PlayerStatus.appliedEffects.Exists(ae => PlayerStatus.FindAE(ae, 1)))
{
    PlayerStatus.doubleBullets = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int ndx = PlayerStatus.appliedEffects.FindIndex(ae => PlayerStatus.FindAE(ae, 1));
```

The parameter to FindIndex is a method/lambda with one argument. In this case, a lambda is created which takes a single parameter `ae`, and returns `FindAE(ae, 1)`.

The `FindAE` method isn't necessary. It might be easier to do this:

```
int ndx = PlayerStatus.appliedEffects.FindIndex(ae => ae.index == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the .Exists thingie instead.